# Why is Photoshop A3 size is bigger compared to Corel Draw A3? And how to solve that....?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, corel-draw, file-size, canvas

I'm used to design a small icon / graphic art, rather than
the big size of A3 paper.

So then When i tried to **use A3** as the **Paper Size** with **resolution of 300 dpi**.
The file size is **bigger** in **Photoshop compared to** the file size in **CorelDraw**.

Is there **any calculation** that we need to use
for achieving a **smaller size** for **designing**
but the image is safe for **later use in printing**?

file size : more than kilobytes, it's bigger than megabytes.

Comment: Bigger on screen. Or bigger in millimetres?

Comment: are both at 100% zoom?

Comment: Your use of bold text here and there makes your text hard to read :) When you say "file size", do you mean the width and height of the image? (It sounds like the size of the file, e.g. kilobytes)

Comment: zoom @SaturnsEye... does it make a difference by zoom? I never heard of it. Bigger in size MG_,.... Yes, HenrikEkblom.... so how to solve this case?

Comment: There is nothing you can do about this. Corel Draw is a vector program and will save everything in that format making the file sizes very small. The photoshop file is all bitmap based so it will save bigger files.